# Remove Elements from Dataframe Based on Group Appearance Rate

Tags: pandas

I have a simple dataframe that is basically a list of objects with their own list of items (see below). What is the cleanest method of filtering out all rows in the overall dataframe based on their rate of occurrence within each group? For example, I want to remove all rows that appear in groups at least 75% of the time. In this example table, I would expect all rows with '30' in column 2 to be deleted, because it appears in 3 out of the 4 groups. Is this a use case for a lambda filter? If so, what would the filter be?

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 7 |
| 0 | 15 |
| 0 | 30 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 |
| 2 | 17 |
| 2 | 29 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
condition = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Col2'])['Col1'].count() / len(df['Col1'].drop_duplicates())<0.75
condition = condition[condition].index
print(df[df['Col2'].isin(condition)])
```

Output:

```
    Col1  Col2
0      0     3
1      0     7
2      0    15
4      1     5
5      1     6
6      1    11
8      2     1
9      2     9
10     2    17
11     2    29
12     3     2
13     3    14
14     3    18
```

Comment: Outstanding. It didn't look very clean at first but now I understand what you did. Thanks for helping a rookie out!